# Cmake, Ninja,BATS, build on windows - Clion style

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, build, ninja

So I'm trying to automate/centralize building of my apps. There is a lot of them and I can't really keep jumping between IDE to build each of them... so the time has come for BATs... Oh yes... I come from Clion, and its a bit of a dramatic experience so far...

So here is my current bat >

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

pushd S:\path\to\src\CMakeLists

call "S:\path\to\cmake\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="S:\path\to\ninja\ninja.exe" -G Ninja S:\path\to\src\CMakeLists\codeCore\

:: "S:\path\to\cmake\cmake.exe" --build "S:\path\to\src\CMakeLists\build\debug" --target all
```

Now for the moment... I'm not building it, as that just ends up in >
`Error: could not load cache`

In any case.
He is currently placing CmakeFiles in wrong location, I want him to place in build/debug or build/debugRelease, so how can I control the placement of that file?
Hes also making:

```
build.ninja
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeCache.txt
```

Which I either don't want or I would prefer to place them in build/debug folder next to rest of cmakeFiles...
What command/where do I need to pass to specify that the folder location?
Clion usually puts everything neatly in to where I specify in settings... and he does not print what exact command he uses to do it so I have to... magic it up.

Any ideas?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Naturally 10 seconds after posting I figured it out...
So my working directory... if I make it in to  `pushd S:\path\to\src\CMakeLists\build\debug`

Then everything goes in to right place!

So for any1 else who needs it... Make sure your working directory is the build/output one.